# Python: json normalize "String indices must be integers" error

Tags: python, json, normalization

I am getting a type error as "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in the following code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

full_json_df = pd.read_json('data/world_bank_projects.json')
json_nor = json_normalize(full_json_df, 'mjtheme_namecode')
json_nor.groupby('name')['code'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
```

```
Output:
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-9401e8bf5427> in <module>()
      1 # Find the top 10 major project themes (using column 'mjtheme_namecode')
      2 
----> 3 json_nor = json_normalize(full_json_df, 'mjtheme_namecode')
      4 #json_nor.groupby('name')['code'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Can you share a piece of that .json file you read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), for `data` argument of the method `json_normalize` :

> data : dict or list of dicts Unserialized JSON objects

In above, `pd.read_json` returns `dataframe`.
So, you can try converting `dataframe` to `dictionary` using `.to_dict()`. There are various options for using [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) as well.

May be something like below:

```
json_normalize(full_json_df.to_dict(), ......)
```

Comment: Indeed `orient="records"` may be useful.