# How to read in pandas dataframe complex JSON files containing many down levels

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I already browsed Stack Overflow and many sites, but I could not find a solution resolving my problem.
I am trying to convert a JSON file received from a multi-dimensionnal inference engine (AI), to an Excel format through a pandas dataframe.
This JSON file has a quite complex structure with many levels down (I am not familiar with JSON language).

Here is the JSON format:

```
    {
"data": {
    "queries": [{
            "id": 292,
            "**name**": "Data_8",
            "queryId": 0,
            "values": {
                "Entreprise": {
                    "F1": {
                        "rule": 1450,
                        "**value**": "1.000000000000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": 430,
            "name": "Data_9",
            "queryId": 1,
            "values": {
                "Entreprise": {
                    "F1": {
                        "rule": 1437,
                        "value": "N"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": 359,
            "**name**": "Data_10",
            "queryId": 2,
            "values": {
                "Entreprise": {
                    "F1": {
                        "rule": 876,
                        "**value**": "O"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, and so on.
```

I load this file with:

```
    with open(output_JSON) as data_file:    
         data2= json.load(data_file)
```

From the file, I need to retrieve only two fields: **name** and the correspondant **value**, in two columns.

Desired output of the dataframe is :

```
              name            value
   0          Data_8            1
   1          Data_9            N
   2          Data_10           O
```

Thank you for your time and your help.

Anyway, take care and stay safe @ home.

Greetings from Paris, France  :)

UPDATE (2/05/2020):
File is loaded with :

```
with open(output_JSON) as data_file:    
             data2= json.load(data_file)
```

then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data2['data'])
print (df)
```

returns:

```
                                              queries
0   {'id': 292, 'name': 'Data_8', 'queryId': 0, 'v...
1   {'id': 430, 'name': 'Data_9', 'queryId': 1, 'v...
2   {'id': 359, 'name': 'Data_10', 'queryId': 2, '...
```

then:

```
df2=df["queries"]
print (df2)
```

returns quite the same:

```
0     {'id': 292, 'name': 'Data_8', 'queryId': 0, 'v...
1     {'id': 430, 'name': 'Data_9', 'queryId': 1, 'v...
2     {'id': 359, 'name': 'Data_10', 'queryId': 2, '...
```

At this point I dont know how to get name and value columns in a dataframe.

Thank you again for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `json_normalize`

- If the pandas version is < 1, use `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`

#### `data2`

- This is the data I have in a file called `test.json`

```py
{
    "data": {
        "queries": [{
                "id": 292,
                "name": "Data_8",
                "queryId": 0,
                "values": {
                    "Entreprise": {
                        "F1": {
                            "rule": 1450,
                            "value": "1.000000000000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "id": 430,
                "name": "Data_9",
                "queryId": 1,
                "values": {
                    "Entreprise": {
                        "F1": {
                            "rule": 1437,
                            "value": "N"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "id": 359,
                "name": "Data_10",
                "queryId": 2,
                "values": {
                    "Entreprise": {
                        "F1": {
                            "rule": 876,
                            "value": "O"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  # not needed for current pandas
from pathlib import Path
import json

# load test.json
p = Path(r'c:\Users\...\test.json')

with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data2 = json.loads(f.read())


# create the dataframe
# df = pd.json_normalize(data2, ['data', 'queries'])  # use for modern pandas
df = json_normalize(data2, ['data', 'queries'])

df.rename(columns={'values.Entreprise.F1.value': 'value'}, inplace=True)

df2 = df[['name', 'value']].copy()

print(df)

    id     name  queryId  values.Entreprise.F1.rule           value queries.name
0  292   Data_8        0                       1450  1.000000000000          NaN
1  430   Data_9        1                       1437               N          NaN
2  359  Data_10        2                        876               O          NaN

print(df2)

      name           value
0   Data_8  1.000000000000
1   Data_9               N
2  Data_10               O
```

Comment: I fixed the double quotes in the sample JSON file and rerun the code, But got the following error : " TypeError: string indices must be integers" because of                           " df = json_normalize(data2, ['data', 'queries']) "

Comment: @EricX You should probably update pandas at this point.  I'm on 1.0.3.  You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710154/python-json-normalize-string-indices-must-be-integers-error to fix the error.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but the installation of Python for my client is 3.6.1, and pandas lversion number is 0.20.1. I have to deal with it, because of compatibility.

Comment: I thank you warmly for your help @Trenton, you gave me some ideas, and it seems I will find a solution in the next days.The strange thing is that I already processed a JSON file without any problem and got a correct dataframe for it with needed columns